# Stylelint Webstorm displaying errors in the top of the file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, eslint, prettier, stylelint

I have installed stylelint in my empty nextjs project using this [guide](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/get-started).

It works as expected, but I have 2 problems:

1. For files which have no problems, it displays this notification all the time:
   [image]
2. If a file has an error/errors, it displays it also in the notification at top of the file instead for every error per line:
   [image]

Questions:

1. How to disable this annoying notification in 1st case?
2. How to highlight errors in code instead of listing them in notification like in the 2nd case?